# Как применить кастомный шрифт из папки без его установки к лейблу в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу десктоп приложение на C# + WPF

Имеется лейбл `CategoryLabel1`

Есть шрифты в папке fonts
Я бы хотел применить один из шрифтов к лейблу, но так,чтобы не надо было его устанавливать, так как в дальнейшем шрифты будут паковаться в инсталятор и программа будет  устанавливаться на разные компьютеры.

Желательно бы програмный способ, так как кастомные шрифты будут ещё отображаться в combobox, и ещё названия этих шрифтов будут храниться в settings файле

**Как это можно сделать?**
[image: Fonts]

[image: Fonts 2]

Comment: путь к шрифтам записываем в ресурсы [описание](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN#adding-fonts-as-resource-items)

Comment: Это уже сделано, название шрифта автоматические добавлено в файл ToolkitsNew.csproj